# How to create print popup in asp.net MVC

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i want to open print popup while clicking print button.The print popup should be like below image.[here i want to print pdf file while clicking print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jW91Y.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Data table to solve your problem.Click the below link to check it.

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/simple.html